# Is there a way to circumnavigate the globe only passing through points which have the same temperature as their antipodes?

Tags: general-topology

Define a circumnavigation to be a closed path connecting antipodal points. Let $f(x)$ be the temperature on point $x$ on the surface of the earth and assume it is continuous, and let $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$. We have that $g(x)=g(-x)$ so for any point $x$ and any path $P$ connecting $x$ and $-x$ we have that either $g(x)=0$ or there's a point in $P$ that maps to zero. That's easy to prove with the intermediate value theorem. So if we take $x$ to be the north pole and $P$ to be a meridian we have have that every meridian has a zero in it, and $g$ is continuous so we have that there's a path that goes around in the east-west direction that only goes through points where $g$ is zero. So we could have that this path goes through only the north hemisphere, which would be a circumnavigation by naval standards but now the way I defined it, like this:

[image]

$g$ is odd so there has to be a symmetric path on the southern hemisphere. But then how do we guarantee that the paths meet? We can repeat the process by taking $x$ to be points other than the north pole and $P$ to be great circles containing $x$, so for each point on the planet we have that there's a way to go around it and back to where you started going only through points where $g$ is zero. This feels like it would allow you to stitch up the paths together and get a circumnavigation, but I haven't been able to wrap it up.

Comment: If $g(x) = 0$ where $x$ is the north pole, there could be some meridians that are not crossed by the path, which would then not be a circumnavigation in the usual sense (though it might still be one according to your definition).

Comment: @DavidK that's true. I was thinking about the case where $g$ isn't zero at the north pole. In that case you have to choose another point to start the analysis in. And that wouldn't be a valid circumnavigation, unless you managed to connect the two poles.

Comment: I don't think this is really a problem with your approach, because if $g$ is not identically zero you can just choose one of the points where it's non-zero to be your north pole.